# $location.path is giving 304 Not Modified

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using AngularJS with Rails 4.1. I have following in my controller js...

`$scope.go = function(path) {
   $location.path(path);
 };`

So, when I call `ng-click="go('/home')"` nothing happens and I get `304 Not Modified` in Console. However, if I do `href="#/home"` it works.